# Unable to connect to SQL Server Express in visual studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019, sql-server-express

I am trying to connect to my SQL Server Express using migration. The migration is successful but while updating I am getting an error.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

**appsetings.json**

```
{
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Microsoft": "Warning",
  "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DemoLoginContextConnection": "Server=(DESKTOP-48LBLF\\SQLEXPRESS)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=DemoLogin;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
}
```

**SSMS**

[image]

Comment: That's an invalid `server` value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried to add a valid one but still it's not working

Comment: Have you checked services.msc and verified that the SQL Server instance is actually running?

Comment: @TiesonT. yes the sql server is running

Comment: @Moeez what *did* you try? The error you got when you tried this invalid connection string doesn't count. There are a *lot* of duplicate questions for this specific error and the reason is always a wrong server name or an inaccessible server, either because it's not running or because it's blocked by a firewall

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my SSMS is working perfectly alright.

Comment: @Moeez which means your connection string is wrong. Or you're trying to connect to a remote server that doesn't allow remote connections.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried each and every possible solution but still unable to resolve my problem

Comment: @Moeez tried *what exactly*? There are no tricks required to connect to SQL Server, no matter the edition. The very fact you can connect using another client tool, SSMS, means the problem is in your code and connection string. You *haven't* posted your code or a valid connection string yet. Or even code that actually reproduces the error. Just a JSON string

Comment: @Moeez are you sure you're using the correct settings file? Create a new, empty console application and add *only* the minimum code needed to connect using a hard-coded connection string. Just create a `SqlConnection` object with the hard-coded connection string and call `Open()`. Try that on the same machine where you used SSMS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your screenshot shows - the server/instance name should be just `DESKTOP-48LBLF\\SQLEXPRESS` - not what you have right now....

Try this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DemoLoginContextConnection": "Server=DESKTOP-48LBLF\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=DemoLogin;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

Comment: Tried but same result

Comment: The problem was the connection string. But It should be added before migration not after migration